# DatePickerDialog Issue in Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am unable to see the initials of Day in DatePickerDialog

[image]

What I want is :

[image]

The code I am using for showing dialog is :

```
 DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, startingDateSetListener,
                    starting_date_object.getYear(),
                    starting_date_object.getMonthOfYear()-1,
                    starting_date_object.getDayOfMonth());

            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(ending_date_object.getMillis());
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: Post some code which you have tried.

Comment: Show code display Picker Dialog.

Comment: Code updated. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The days are probably there but their `textColor` is the same as the background so you can't see them. This has to do with the style/theme of the dialog.  
Create a theme in `styles.xml` like:

```
<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_accent_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_control_activated_color</item>
</style>
```

and initialize the DatePickerDialog by supplying the theme:

```
 DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                    R.style.DatePickerTheme, 
                    startingDateSetListener,
                    starting_date_object.getYear(),
                    starting_date_object.getMonthOfYear()-1,
                    starting_date_object.getDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: I'm glad_______